# Android - Center image on Toolbar with menu inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, android-toolbar

I'm trying to center the text on Toolbar taking in consideration the menu that is being inflated on Activity. I find many solutions on SO, but didn't find anything that covers the case where a menu is also inflated.

If I only inflate an `ImageView` without inflating the `menu`, everything is ok.
If I inflate the `ImageView` and the `menu` then the `image` doesn't get displayed in the center of `Toolbar`, but center on its own space (between hamburger and menu)

**Conclusion:**

I need to center `ImageView` on `Toolbar`, no matter if something later is inflated or not. The `menu` i am inflating at the moment only has one `item` (a switch, always visible)

**Here is my current code:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Activity:

```
...    
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_toolbar_user_visibility, menu);
        return true;
    }
...
```

How can I center the ImageView even after a menu is inflated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If I inflate the imageView and the menu then the image doesn't get
>   displayed in the center of toolbar, but center on its own space
>   (between hamburger and menu).

This is happening because, you have added `ImageView` inside `Toolbar` and as your `Toolbar` is using as `ActionBar`, so it uses some `left` spaces for `back` or `drawer` icon and `right` space for option `menu`.

```
Toolbar = "Back arrow" + "Middle area(Title/Image)" + "Option menu"
```

**SOLUTION:**

**1.** Add a `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `AppBarLayout`.

**2.** Put `Toolbar` and `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout`.

**3.** Add attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `imageView` to show at `center` of `Toolbar`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Your Content here -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**In your activity, add below lines:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(""); // hide title
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you :) If my answer seems useful, you can vote it up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you may create separate layout which let you ignore the toolbar itself and align freely and include it after toolbar layout. remove title by `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`.(this is offcurse a drawer activity and *fragments* but you can ignore  )

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/splashback"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    >

    <!-- your main fragment content layout -->
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <!-- your action bar (customised) layout -->
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"/>

    <!-- GO TO CENTER MORON LOGO layout -->
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbarlogo"/>

    <!-- drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_head"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarx"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbarlogo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:src="@drawable/logotoolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```